# Solve the integro-differential equation $x^2 \frac{dy}{dx}+\int_{0}^{x} t^2y^5(t)dt=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

If $y$ is a function of $x$ then solve

The integro-differential equation $$x^2 \frac{dy}{dx}+\int_{0}^{x} t^2y^5(t)dt=0$$

I tried to differentiate both sides w.r.t $x$ we get

$$x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2x\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2y^5=0$$ $\implies$

$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+xy^5=0$$

Letting $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$ we have a Linear differential equation as:

$$\frac{dp}{dx}+\frac{2p}{x}=-y^5$$ using Integrating factor method we get

$$px^2=-\int x^2y^5dx+C$$

How to proceed from here?

Comment: We don't really have a linear equation here, because of how $p$ is related to $y$, so the integrating factor method won't help. Worse still, because the original problem is nonlinear, we might not be able to provably find all solutions. Let's try an Ansatz $y=Ax^n,\,A\ne 0$ (since $y=0$ is a trivial solution), so $\int_0^x t^2 y^5 dt=\frac{A^2}{5n+3}x^{5n+3}$, reducing the original equation to $nAx^{n+1}=-\frac{A^2}{5n+3}x^{5n+3}$, and you can solve for $A$ and $n$.

Comment: Another form that you can get is $(xy)''+xy^5=0$, but that is also of limited utility.

Answer (score 6):

In [Polyanin A., D., Zaitsev V. F., Handbook of exact solutions for ordinary differential equations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257913343_Handbook_of_Exact_Solutions_for_Ordinary_Differential_Equations)
the ODE
\begin{equation}
 x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+xy^5=0
\end{equation} 
is mentioned as a solvable case of a modified Emden-Fowler Equation:
\begin{equation}
 xy''+\frac{2n+m+3}{m-1}y'=Ax^{n+1}y^m
\end{equation} 
Here, $n=0,m=5,A=-1$. Its solution in parametric form is (2.6.3):
\begin{align}
 x&=\exp\left( -2C_2\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{C_1+t^2/4-t^6/3}} \right)\\
 y&=t\exp\left( C_2\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{C_1+t^2/4-t^6/3}} \right)
\end{align}
It can be checked by introducing the form $x=\exp(g(t)),y=t\exp(-g(t)/2)$ in the initial ODE. Then $g(t)$ verifies
$$ 4g''(t)-t(4t^4-1)[g'(t)]^3=0$$